# AngularJS routing for Kendo UI mobile

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-routing

I'm starting to develop mobile application with Kendo UI mobile, AngularJS, PhoneGap. It would be nice to use Angular routing stuff. But Kendo UI mobile has its own routing system. Are any approaches to use AngularJS routing system instead of Kendo UI mobile?

Maybe some wrappers...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I've searched everywhere to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, routing for Angularjs is all client based, so you can use it without needing the kendoui routing, You just need to setup your routing for angular. You can route to any url you would like. That said, if you need specific functionality that that Kendoui provides, it has a client side version of the routing you can use JavaScript to combine the two, the syntax for the routing for both are very similar.